# Codeigniter Code Injected in Index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, security

I have a codeigniter project and I see the index.php page keep getting hacked

Some code is added automatically every time on the top of the index.php page and my site is redirected to third party url whenever i click anywhere.

The injected code is as follows:

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set("display_errors", 0);
include_once(sys_get_temp_dir()."/SESS_48cd7517d21176f980daa5502d9efb31");
```

How can i prevent this?

Comment: There is no definitive way to prevent code injection. First step should be to check in logfiles and look for any suspicious queries. You might be able to find those parts in queries if it's been hacked.

Comment: Yes i find the some suspicious code in log file Call to undefined function get_transient() in /home/irma1000/public_html/Project Name/deleteme.wpplu9.php on line 16.I try to find this function but this function not available in my project.So how can i solve this one?

Comment: Can you see a log in which it's not undefined? Is there any creation/removal/modification of this file?

Comment: undefined function get_transient() I search this function in to my project but not find it..this is not my project related anymore...

Comment: Wath I meant is, if you can find this function anywhere else in logfiles. The error more likely is correct at that time. Function isn't defined right now, but it might have existed at some point and been removed.